# OverflowStrategy not taking into account?

Tags: java, reactive, reactor

I created a Flux that procudes continuously a new interger value. I have a subscriber running in its own thread (`.publishOn(single())` ). No matter what strategy I use (LATEST or another), I always get the same result :

```
*** Received 1 with thread single-1
>>> Generated 1 with thread main
>>> Generated 2 with thread main
>>> Generated 3 with thread main
>>> Generated 4 with thread main
>>> Generated 5 with thread main
>>> Generated 6 with thread main
>>> Generated 7 with thread main
>>> Generated 8 with thread main
>>> Generated 9 with thread main
*** Received 2 with thread single-1
*** Received 3 with thread single-1
*** Received 4 with thread single-1
*** Received 5 with thread single-1
*** Received 6 with thread single-1
*** Received 7 with thread single-1
```

From what I understood, by setting `latest`, I should only received the last integers.. some integers should have been dropped ?

```
@Test
    @DisplayName("test")
    public void workingFlux() throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        Flux<Integer> IntGenerator = Flux.create(e -> {
            AtomicInteger iteration = new AtomicInteger(1);
            while (iteration.intValue() < 10) {
                int value = iteration.getAndIncrement();
                e.next(value);
                if (value < 10) {
                    System.out.println(">>> Generated " + value + " with thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            }
        }, FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.DROP);

        IntGenerator.publishOn(single())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {
                    private Subscription s;

                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(final Subscription subscription) {
                        s = subscription;
                        s.request(1);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(final Integer integer) {
                        System.out.println("*** Received " + integer + " with thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(10000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        s.request(1);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(final Throwable throwable) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
Flux<Integer> IntGenerator = Flux.create(e -> {
            AtomicInteger iteration = new AtomicInteger(1);
            while (iteration.intValue() < 10) {
                int value = iteration.getAndIncrement();
                e.next(value);
                if (value < 10) {
                    System.out.println(">>> Generated " + value + " with thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            }
        }, FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.LATEST);

        IntGenerator.publishOn(single())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {
                    private Subscription s;

                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(final Subscription subscription) {
                        System.out.println("Subscribed");
                        s = subscription;
                        s.request(1);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(final Integer integer) {
                        System.out.println("*** Received " + integer + " with thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(10000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        s.request(1);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(final Throwable throwable) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });

        latch.await(120L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        latch.await(120L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

Comment: What is the question you have? And/or what is the result you expect? Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0):

publishOn has an internal buffer with a 32 item capacity by default so you are not generating enough items.